# How to insert banner ad only at 1st position of list view?

Tags: android, android-listview, admob

http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.in/2012/03/embedding-admob-ads-within-listview-on.html refering this link for inserting ad in nth position. But i want to insert at only 1st position now

=================================================================================
Below code is to insert at nth postion[working fine]

public AllTopicsAdapter(Context context, BaseAdapter delegate) {

```
    this.context = context;
    this.delegate = delegate;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Total count includes list items and ads.
    return delegate.getCount()+2;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // Return null if an item is an ad. Otherwise return the delegate item.
    if (isItemAnAd(position)) {
        return null;
    }
    return delegate.getItem(getOffsetPosition(position));
}

@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return (!isItemAnAd(position))
            && delegate.isEnabled(getOffsetPosition(position));
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private boolean isItemAnAd(int position) {
    // Place an ad at the first and last list view positions.
    return (position == 0 || position == (getCount() - 1));
}

private int getOffsetPosition(int position) {
    return position - 1;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int k = 2;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if ((position % k) == 0) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adview, null);
        // set ad content
        convertView.setBackground(null);
        moPubView = (MoPubView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.adview);

        moPubView.setAdUnitId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

        moPubView.setBannerAdListener(this);
        moPubView.loadAd();
        return convertView;
    }

    else {

        return delegate.getView(position - (int) Math.ceil(position / k)- 1, convertView, parent);
    }
}
```

=========================================================================================
//trying to insert ad in first position. But in this case it is replacing my item.

```
                   if (position== 1) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adview, null);
        // set ad content
        convertView.setBackground(null);
        moPubView = (MoPubView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.adview);

        moPubView.setAdUnitId("b2bd1dff9963441aaa1b9603bcf6d5d3");

        moPubView.setBannerAdListener(this);
        moPubView.loadAd();
        return convertView;
    }

    else {


        return delegate.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
```

0,ad,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 <--------- like this

Comment: i hope try to my ans and implement it in your code might it'll be work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do one think.

```
@Override
        public int getCount()
        {

            return item.size()+1;
        }
```

and in

@Override

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView)
{

    if (position == 0)
    {
        // ad
    } else if(position>0)
    {
        item.get(position - 1);// access array by deducting -1 .
    }

}
```

Comment: 05-27 12:38:21.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2748): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1

the above code showing this error, beacuse for position=0, it is giving -1 index
item.get(position - 1);

Comment: asking for one more return statement now.

Comment: you have to inflate layout as per position. if (position==0) then return view; view which is for advertisement. and in else part inflate layout which you want to show in listview.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [`addHeaderView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) of `ListView`. It allows you to provide a `View` that will act as a header (it will be inserted at the 1st position of the `ListView`) of your `ListView`.

Comment: if i am not wrong , addHeaderView() works only for adding element at top of the list.
but in this case i want to insert element after position 0. that is 1st position of list view.

Comment: If you just want to show a `View` at the first position of the `ListView` just put an `if(){...}` that checks the `position` variable you get passed into `getView()`.

Comment: but that will replace the item of 1st position.

Comment: Yes, it will. Do you want to show the ad as the first item of the `ListView`?

Comment: 0,ad,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12   <--------- like this

Comment: Hey @Emmanuel you are trying to justify the and as your way and i trying my way So...

Comment: Then you need to tell the `ListView` that you will be using two different `Views` in it. You do this by overriding `getViewType()` and `getViewTypeCount()` in your adapter and providing the logic I said above.

Comment: Here is a [link](http://learnncode.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/listview-getviewtype-and-getviewtypecount-in-action/) on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

try this hope it works

```
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
ListView listView = getListView();
listView.addHeaderView(header);
```

Comment: if i am not wrong , addHeaderView() works only for adding element at top of the list. but in this case i want to insert element after position 0. that is 1st position of list view.

Comment: How is this different than my answer? Just because you show code? Code only answers are discouraged in SO.

Comment: Code-only answers are not a good fit for SO as they aren't as helpful to future visitors. Try to include an explanation of what you have changed and why it should work.